# Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'?

Tags: angular

Im using this block in my html template :

```
  <div *ngIf="visibleblock && !selected?.item?.externalInfo?.length > 0">
```

But im getting this error when i do:

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

Any suggestion how can i fix this ?

Comment: Why the `!` before `selected?.item?.externalInfo?.length`

Comment: <div *ngIf="visibleblock && !(selected?.item?.externalInfo?.length > 0)">

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Put the second expression inside parenthesis:

```
<div *ngIf="visibleblock && !(selected?.item?.externalInfo?.length > 0)">
```

Comment: Its working.. Can you explain what is the difference between these ?

Comment: @Krunal For example: `!a.length` returns a boolean value because it will check if the length of `a` exists. So writing `(!a.length > 0)` will compare a boolean value to 0. `!(a.length > 0)` will check if the comparison inside the paranthesis (number versus number) is a boolean value true or false. That's the difference and that's why OP got an error message.